# Is the law of the equality of inertial and gravitational mass valid in all possible cases?

Tags: general-relativity, mass, reference-frames, tidal-effect, equivalence-principle

I have been thinking about equivalence principle (**EP**) for a while and I am intrigued about the following.

A classical example to explain **EP**:

1. On the one hand, imagine we have an elevator (**e_1**) located in space and it is uniformly accelerated (**a**) with someone inside.
2. On the other hand, imagine we have an elevator (**e_2**) located in the surface of the earth and it is subjected to earth's gravity (**g**).

It is accepted **a = g**, so theoretically we can not distinguish between **e_1** and **e_2**.

But wait a second.

If we analyse **e_1** we will realize the entire elevator and the person inside are uniformly accelerated equally. That is okey, what we expected.

But if we analyse **e_2** the entire elevator will not be subjected to the same **g**! I confess it was a beautiful moment for me when I realized.

**g** = GMe/Re^2 As we increse elevator's height, **g** dicreases. Doing some research, I learnt this phenomena is called tidal force.

So if I am not wrong, I guess the law of the equality of inertial and gravitational mass is not valid in all cases. We could only accept it when elevator (in this example) is small enough (**g** will not suffer a significant change).

Could we avoid tidal force rotating e_2?

Comment: "It is accepted **a = g**".  That's an assumption you have _to make_, it's not something that we "accept".  Acceleration can be many different values, "g" is just the acceleration due to gravity on Earth at sea level.  They are equivalent as long as $a = g$, which would require $a$ to change as $g$ does.  The principle says that when the accelerations are the same it will hold, in your example the accelerations diverge and it no longer holds.  Nothing special about it really.

Comment: Do you know what general relativity is?

Comment: The equivalence principle talks about local experiments. The presence of measurable tidal forces means the experiment is not local.